# Embedding a JS file in Silverlight Class Library

Tags: javascript, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, class-library

I am trying to create a Silverlight class library which needs to call a few Javascript methods. I have put these methods in a single .js file and have added it to the project. But when I try to call any of the methods in the js file, I get a FailedtoInvoke error. I understand that this problem can be solved by adding a reference of the JS file in the head section of ASPX or HTML page. But I am developing a class library and so that is not possible. Does someone know how to tackle this issue? I am using Silverlight 4 and Visual Studio 2010.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the .js file to your library probject as it sounds you have done, make sure it Build Action is "Resource".

You can retrieve this content with `Application.GetResourceStream` :-

```
StreamResourceInfo sriJS = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("YourAssemblyName;component/MyStuff.js", UriKind.Relative));
```

Note the structure of the Uri, the assembly name of your class library is needed followed by the literal ";component".  This tells Silverlight to look for a resource inside your dll that will be included in a final application's Xap.

Now you need to turn the content of the info's `Stream` property into a string:-

```
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(sriJS.Stream, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
string js = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

Finally you can inject that javascript into the current page with:-

```
HtmlPage.Window.Eval(js);
```

Thats it, any global functions defined in the js may now be invoked with `HtmlPage.Window.Invoke`.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
string myScriptCodeString = GetScriptCodeStringFromSomewhere();
System.Windows.Browser.HtmlPage.Window.Eval(myScriptCodeString);
```

Then the methods defined in `myScriptCodeString` should be available.

Comment: For this to work, I need to host my js file in my server separately and then call it here right?

Comment: You could host that script somewhere on the server and load it async with the `WebClient` class and execute the above code in its callback. But you could also define that `myScriptCodeString` hard-coded in your library. Hard-coded script strings are not so nice however, so yet another option would be to look at the Scriptable Object functionality [ http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645085(VS.95).aspx ] if that's a possibility for your scenario.